# Django Deployment on windows

Tags: django, apache

I am learning python and Django now. I have a question related to deploying Django project on windows 7. I know how to start the test server in django and see the project. But I have to do start the server manually every time I restart the PC. Also I have to keep the terminal window open.

Consider the below scenario for php projects.
We copy and paste the php files in htdocs or www folder in apache server and access them using the respected url. Web Server is running in the background. We dont have to start the server on windows restart.

Is something similar possible with Django on apache or any other server?
If yes, how should I go about it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: still stuck at this issue.
made some changes by looking at the tutorial you suggested earlier. and the above document.
Now i can type the url as localhost/mysite and index of my site is shown. I can see the files in the folder.
How to get past this?

Comment: can you repost the earlier tutorial please?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling around for an answer to a similar problem with deploying Django on a Windows server, here is a guide

- [Deploy Django with Apache and mod_wsgi on Windows Server 2019](https://youtu.be/frEjX1DNSpc)

To have Apache24 service automatically run on startup, make the changes in [Windows Services](https://www.howtogeek.com/school/using-windows-admin-tools-like-a-pro/lesson8/) dialog.

Comment: Just linking to your own library or tutorial is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code on how to do so and disclaiming that you wrote it makes for a better answer. See: [**What signifies “Good” self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212)